# Problems while building neo4j mazerunner project

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, docker, docker-compose, neo4j-mazerunner

While building a project when i run these 2 command line in ubuntu it shows me the following errors:

```
$docker build -t workspace/stageprojet .

--2016-08-01 14:33:06--  https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mazerunner-artifacts/spark-1.1.2-RELEASE-driver.jar
Resolving s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com (s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.237.77
Connecting to s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com (s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com)|54.231.237.77|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-08-01 14:33:07 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

The command '/bin/sh -c wget https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mazerunner-artifacts/spark-1.1.2-RELEASE-driver.jar' returned a non-zero code: 8


$docker-compose up -d 
ERROR:         
     Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any         parent. Are you in the right directory?     
     Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

**EDIT1 : Dockerfile**

This is the Dockerfile that i used the project

```
# Dockerizing Neo4j Mazerunner: Dockerfile for building graph analytics
# applications.

FROM       java:openjdk-8-jdk
MAINTAINER K.B. Name <kb@socialmoon.com>

USER root

# Set the default HDFS and Spark hosts
ENV SPARK_HOST local
ENV HDFS_HOST hdfs://hdfs:9000
ENV DRIVER_HOST mazerunner
ENV RABBITMQ_HOST localhost
ENV SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY 6g
ENV HADOOP_HOME /etc/hadoop
ENV MAZERUNNER_HOME /etc/mazerunner
ENV CLASSPATH /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hadoop/*:/etc/mazerunner/*:/etc/mazerunner/lib/*
ENV SPARK_CLASSPATH /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hadoop/*:/etc/mazerunner/*:/etc/mazerunner/lib/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN mkdir /etc/mazerunner

# Update apt-get
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y -qq install erlang-nox && \
    mkdir /etc/rabbitmq && \
    echo "[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]." > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config && \
    echo "deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list && \
    curl -quiet -L -o ~/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc http://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc && \
    apt-key add ~/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc && \
    apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -y -qq --allow-unauthenticated --force-yes install rabbitmq-server && \
    apt-get clean

# Copy bootstrapper
COPY sbin/mazerunner.sh /etc/mazerunner/bootstrap.sh
RUN chown root:root /etc/mazerunner/bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod 700 /etc/mazerunner/bootstrap.sh

# Copy Spark's HDFS configurations
RUN mkdir /etc/hadoop
COPY conf/hadoop /etc/hadoop

# Copy Mazerunner service binary
WORKDIR /etc/mazerunner
RUN wget https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mazerunner-artifacts/spark-1.1.2-RELEASE-driver.jar

ENV BOOTSTRAP /etc/mazerunner/bootstrap.sh

CMD ["/etc/mazerunner/bootstrap.sh", "-d"]
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this ?

**EDIT 2**

When i look for docker-compose.yml i find it in many directories

[image]

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: @cml.co i added the dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose up -d` is looking for a `docker-compose.yml` in the current directory and it can't find one. Does the file exist? If you're not running multiple containers, you may need instead to use `docker run`

Comment: no but i have found many docker-compose.yml files in different directories i have posted the screen capture